# Cakephp database session destroy handler makes the page unresponded

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm trying to do the database session in my CakePHP application. Everything is fine so far.
The problem is that when I try to log out, the page is taking too long to respond and got the message "The connection was reset".

Even if my `MySession.destory()` method contains just a line `return true`, the problem still exists. I could see the output `My Session` when I removed the comment from `//echo 'MySession'; exit;`;

When I removed the line `$this->controller->Session->destroy();` from `MyAuthComponent`, it is ok except that the session is not destroyed.

Even if the function `MySession.destroy()` is empty, the problem persists.
The following is my code:

**app\Config\core.php**

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => array(
        'engine' => 'MySession',
        'model'  => 'session'
    )
));
```

**app\Controller\AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $components = array(
    "Session",
    "Token",
    "Auth" => array(
      'className' => 'MyAuth'
    ),
  );
```

**app\Controller\LoginController.php**

```
public function logout() {
    $this->Auth->logout();
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logoutUrl());
}
```

**app\Controller\Component\MyAuthComponent.php**

```
public function logout() { 
    $this->controller->Session->destroy();
    return true;
}
```

**lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Session\MySession.php**
This extends `lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Session\DatabaseSession.php` as I need some customization on this.

```
public function destroy($id) { 
    //echo 'MySession'; exit;
    //if($this->cacheKey) Cache::delete($id, $this->cacheKey);
    //return $this->_model->delete($id, false);
    //return parent::destroy($id);
    return true;
}
```

**Model\Session.php**

```
class Session extends AppModel {
  public $useTable = "cake_sessions";

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function delete($id){    
      $db = $this->getDataSource();
      if($db->delete($this, array($this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey => $id))){
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

My PHP version is 5.2.6 and Cake version is 2.1.3.

### UPDATE on 15 Apr, 2014

The problem does not occur in XAMPP 1.7.4 with PHP 5.3.5. Probably it is a pitfall of lower version of PHP for session destroy callback.